# Karma is not installing in my windows 7 machine. No error either. Showing installation in progress from long time

Tags: node.js, karma-runner

- ### Installed Node.js then Opened command prompt in admin mode and gave "npm install -g karma"

There is no error shown. Its not installing karma also, there is an indication that installtion is in progress. But, its never getting installed.
Below is the screenshot. 
What causes this problem?
Is there any problem with system configuration.
Please provide any idea to install karma successfully.
[image]

Comment: Are you running cmd with elevated privileges? (Run as admin)

Comment: Yes. i am using it as admin.